# How to detect how far the object on photo is from another objects on that photo?

Tags: algorithm, image, detection

So for example we have real life photo. how to get (relativly to image dimentions for example) the distance from wall to girls, from girls to trees if all we know ts this picture?

[image]
<sub>(source: [vkontakte.ru](http://cs388.vkontakte.ru/u19496487/93097195/x_24446bf1.jpg))</sub>

Papers with algorithms and\or Open Source programs doing this would be appreciated. As for me Code is Better than just pure algorithm. So if you give algorithms please give links to Open Source programatic representations of that algorithms!)

So How to detect how far the object on photo is from another objects on that photo?

Comment: Do you mean 2D distance (i.e. in the photo) or 3D distance (i.e. in the real world that the photo represents)? In 2D, the distance of the girls to the trees is clearly 0 (they touch). In 3D, you'd need to know how far away the trees and the girls are from the camera. From a single photograph, this is theoretically impossible to determine.

Comment: 3D distance (but because we do not know relative proportions of real world and the imadge we should say  something like - 1 image pixel is our 1 unit so girls are in 400 units from trees and so on... something  like relative depth) And from From a single photograph, this is theoretically possible=) (Asumitg we have found at least 2 relativly straight lines crossing each other because if we will will find the prespective and knowing prespective ve can do lots of stuff... but only theoretically while I need the code libs=))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to measure the distance of objects from a photo, you need to map these objects in a space representation. If you expect real distance like in real world (3D), you need a 3D space representation.

First, it is better to look at lens and spatial distortions. 
http://www.beyondmegapixels.com/2008/12/spatial-relationships-and-distortion/

Back to the space representation, you need to understand how to build a 3D scene using photography. 
http://www.feargod.net/3dhowto.php

Here is a paper talking about this topic. 
http://www.isprs.org/education/PDF/DAGM-Tutorial-Color.pdf

well, i know the microsoft photosynth ( http://photosynth.net) that can do the reconstruction. ref: http://on10.net/blogs/larry/Fotomo-3D-scenes-from-photos/

Here it is a interesting example of how this technology works http://olympus.co.jp/en/magazine/pursuit/feature_article/…

Googling for photosynth open source projects:
http://code.google.com/p/pixelstruct 
http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler 
http://openphotovr.org  
http://photosynth.net/discussion.aspx?cat=6b63cb81-8b57-4d5d-a978-41d5509bf59a&dis=1de0ba11-2eea-4cb3-907a-252fb30f1200 (more link)

Comment: Are there any open source  programms examples of algorithms you presented?

Comment: well, i know the microsoft photosynth ( photosynth.net) that can do the reconstruction. ref: on10.net/blogs/larry/Fotomo-3D-scenes-from-photos Here it is a interesting work of how this technology works olympus.co.jp/en/magazine/pursuit/feature_article/… Googling for photosynth open source projects: code.google.com/p/pixelstruct phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler openphotovr.org photosynth.net/… (more links) – darlinton 0 secs ago edit

Comment: If you could add links to your answer It would be grate!)